# WPF how to apply a style to a custom control item without overriding the derived style

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design, wpf-controls, material-design-in-xaml

I'm building a custom control search box in wpf based on the [common windows search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CoHx.png) [(my version)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10XJd.png). In the windows implementation the buttons would change background and foreground depending on whether they were pressed or not. To do this I'm using a style and triggers to change the button colors.

As I'm using MaterialDesign my custom control contains a button which uses the derived/default [material design button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DghJy.png). When a style is applied to this button the material design style is [overridden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3SeK.png) in favor for the default wpf button. How can I apply a style while keeping the base material design style?

As my issue is solely with applying a style to a button I have omitted the search box style and instead created an example of my problem containing just a button.

**Generic.xaml -CustomButton**

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomButton}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <!-- Normally the below button would be inside a grid with additional buttons, labels and content presenter. I have removed these for simplicity-->
                        <Button Name="MaterialButton"
                                Content="CustomButton">
                            <Button.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type  Button}}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Button.Style>
                        </Button>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**App.xaml** - (Material Design is in resource dictionary.)

```
 <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

**What I've tried**

I've tried using the `BasedOn` attribute as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495298/how-to-add-a-trigger-to-a-wpf-custom-control-without-overriding-the-existing-sty) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2728943/11522147) however this has not resolved my issue.

Deriving from a material style based on the ["Material Design theme is lost"](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/FAQ) 
FAQ, results in this error:
Exception: Cannot find resource named 'MaterialDesignFlatButton'. Resource names are case sensitive.

**Generic.Xaml Attempted changes to CustomButton**

```
<!--Same custon control as before--->
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}">
        <!--same trigger-->
```

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you haven't installed the correct dependencies. Right-click on the project which uses the style and choose the NuGet package manager. Search for a *MaterialDesignThemes* package and install it. If this is already installed, then reinstall it again. This should fix it.

The rest of your approach is correct.

Alternatively copy the [original style](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Button.xaml) (snapshot) and all references from the GitHub repository and paste it to your *App.xaml*.

If all dependencies are installed (or the original style copied), then use the following `Style` to apply the MaterialDesign default `Button` style to your `CustomButton`:

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomButton" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" />
```

### Update

Now that you have edited your question to provide the necessary details, I can tell what went wrong.

You have not simply extended `Button`, but also overridden the default `Style` of the extended `Button`. Doing this requires a default `Style` to be defined inside the *Generic.xaml* file. This file doesn't allow merged dictionaries due to the way this default resources are resolved. Only references to resources in the same `ResourceDictionary` of *Generic.xaml* are allowed.

To solve this problem, you need to override the default `Style` explicitly. The override `Style` must be in the scope of the `MaterialDesignFlatButton` resource, otherwise the reference won't resolve and cause the error message you had posted before. The following example defines the override `Style`in *App.xaml*:

```
  <Style TargetType="CustomButton" 
         BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

### Remarks

Since you are obviously not interested in a default `Style`, you should merge details of this default `Style` e.g. the `ControlTemplate` into the override `Style`. You can then delete the default `Style` from *Generic.xaml*. You then also need to remove the following lines from the `static` constructor of the custom control e.g. `CustomButton`:

```
DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomButton), 
  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomButton)));
```

After merging the now obsolete default `Style` of `CustomButton` into the override `Style`, the new override `Style` that could look like this:

**App.xaml**

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomButton"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}">
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomButton}">
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
          <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of using the original style, I will use it if I can't find a simple solution.  MaterialDesignThemes seems to be installed correctly and [works as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DghJy.png) when a style is not applied. The problem arises when a style is applied to an item within a custom control - the item defaults to the wpf theme. I can override items outside of a custom control and both the style and material design theme are applied as expected.

Comment: I don't understand. You have posted an error message which reads that the style `MaterialDesignFlatButton` couldn't be resolved. Tht's why I wrote you should lookup and install the MaterialDesignThemes package. So all styles are implicitly applied application wide except for your `CustomButton`? Make sure you are using the right `Style`. It must be `<Style TargetType="local:CustomButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" />`. Try this style. I will update my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the explicit override was an example of what I've tried to resolve the issue. I have since edited my answer to help clarify this. Material Design styles are application wide including items within my custom control. When I apply a style to an item inside my custom control (in this case the "MaterialButton") it loses its material design theme in place of the default wpf. I'm trying to keep the Material design theme while applying a style. This is can be done outside the custom control in a page or window etc. this problem only appears in a custom control.

Comment: Your latest updates shed some light into the darkness. I wasn't aware that you are trying this resource merging inside _Generic.xaml_. How could I know this. Now that you mentioned this, I instantly understood your problem. I have updated my answer to adress this new situation. _Generic.xaml_ doesn't allow merged dictionaries as a reference. All referenced resources must be defined inside the `ResourceDictionary` of _Generic.xaml_. All the time I was expecting you to define the `Style` in _App.xaml_. Please try my answer and let me know if this solved your problem.

Comment: I also realized that your `Controltemplate` of `CustomButton` is quite senseless. There is no need to put a button inside a button. So I removed this redundant inner `Button`. You usually add a simply `ContentPresenter` to the template. This `ContentPresenter` will automatically bind to the `ContentControl.Content` property to render the content value. Please check and try my latest updates.

Comment: From the Update section I need to move my **Generic.xaml** code to **app.xaml** and place it in a resouce dictionary? Thanks for the **App.xaml** code however I'm sorry to say It may not help me. I intended to create a suggestion box custom control that contained buttons with styles hence why my question was about a custom control containing a button. In retrospect this caused a lot of confusion as it was a bizarre example. I have updated my question to give full context for my intended use case and agajn I apologise for th confusion.

Comment: It seems you haven't understood or tried my example. What my example does: it turns the foreground of a MaterialDesign button to red on mouse over. I just took your button behavior to make it work with the MaterialDesign. To change the background on click just trigger on `Button.IsPressed`. As with every style you don't have to put it into App.xaml. You can put it int any `ResourceDictionary` that is in scope of your custom control e.g. `MyCustomControl.Resources`. I just chose App.xaml, because the lack of details from your question and because App.xaml will always work as its scope is global

Comment: What you should've learned from my answer is that you can't merge resources into the `ResourceDictionary` of Generic.xaml or in general reference any resource that is outside Generic.xaml (using `StaticResource`). If you need to access merged resources, then you must do it somewhere else or put those resources directly into Generic.xaml. I think I gave you the solution. Where you finally move this example `Style` to is up to you. Or you must clarify why exactly this isn't working for you. Right now it appears you just didn't understand from reading and refused to try out the example.

Comment: The point is, to reference resources in Generic.xaml that are defined somewhere else, you must use `DynamicResource`. But you can't use `DynamicResource`, when extending styles using `Style.BasedOn`. The value of `Style.BasedOn` must be statically resolvable.